# Issue in advanced search using php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to make search in my Laravel API. 
The query is working fine, if number of words are more than one. But, if you search for a single word it return every field present in that table.

This is my **search query**

```
 $response = strtolower(trim($request->input('data')));
        // separating inputs
            $input = explode(" ", $response);
$items = Items::where(function ($query) use ($input) {
                foreach ($input as $key => $search) {
                    if ($key != 'limit' && $key != 'order' && $key != 'orderWay' && $key != 'page' && $key != 'pluck') {
                            $query->where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%');                        
                    }
                }
         });
```

If you search "Dove Cream" you get an accurate result.

If you search "Dove" all the data in table is returned.

Using arrays (`["dove","cream"]` and `["dove"]`),  the result for input `["Dove"]` is wrong.

Comment: Can you show some rows from your table Items?

Comment: I don't understand the `if `clause, if you use the `explode()` function the resulting array has all keys numeric. Probably you didnt show us all the relevant code and with a single word the `if` takes precedence

Comment: I think, after solving this problem he will send objects with order or limit options.

Comment: It's obvious that this code should work. I vote to close the question until the OP give us a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Vrian7 The rows have data : Cashew Nuts, Baby dove cream, Black gram. On searching Dove Cream , i get : Baby Dove cream. But on searching Dove, I get Cashew Nuts, Baby dove cream, Black gram . All the data

Comment: @dparoli It's for ordering and plucking later

Comment: FYI with explode() your array keys are numeric and the if clause makes no sense, please post a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to make reproducible example. can you guide how to make one?

Comment: @dparoli Opps yeah, you're right.. If is useless here.. Sorry for my silly mistake.. thanks for taking that out